# this vs $scope in AngularJS, 'this' showing peculiar behavior with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have following controller and view in AngularJS and I'm trying to learnt the difference between this and $scope.

//index.js

```
angular.module('angularApp', [])
  .controller('indexCtrl', ($scope)=>{
   // Initialize variables
   $scope.name1 = '';
   this.name2 = '';
   $scope.greeting1 = `Hello ${$scope.name1}`;
   this.greeting2 = `Hi ${this.name2}`;
  })
```

//index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="angularApp">
 <head>
  <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-controller="indexCtrl as app">
   <input
    type="text"
    ng-model="name1"
    placeholder="Using $scope variable name"
   />
   <br />
   <input
    type="text"
    ng-model="app.name2"
    placeholder="Using this variable name"
   />
   <br /><br />
   <h2 ng-if="name1 != ''"> Hello {{name1}} </h2>
   <br />
   <h2 ng-if="app.name2 != ''"> Hi {{app.name2}} </h2>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ideally, when I first run the localhost, it should not show the 'Hello' or the 'Hi' text because of ng-if. While 'Hello' is not displayed, 'Hi' gets displayed. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you are setting `this.name2='';` In this case, `this` is not on `$scope`. So app.name2 != '', it equals `undefined`. It's generally considered better not to use `$scope` directly, but rather to use the ControllerAs syntax (see [this explanation](https://www.codementor.io/cnorthfield/why-you-should-use-angularjs-s-controller-as-syntax-6i001lr5p)).

`$scope` is just a JavaScript object like any other, but it is the implicit scope of anything referred to in the template. Therefore if you have something like `ng-if="name2 == ''"`, name2 refers to a field on $scope.

*When you use ControllerAs, it creates an object on $scope by that name* (`$scope.app` in your case). `$scope.app` corresponds to the controller's `this`. It's exactly the same as if you put `$scope.app = this;` in the controller's JavaScript. So then, in the controller, you could set `this.name2='Harry'` and in the HTML, have:

```
<span> Hi {{app.name2}} </span>
```

And you would see `Hi Harry`.

*However*, you should not use an arrow function to define your controller, since arrow functions do not have their own `this` scope, but inherit it from their parent. When you define functions *on* the controller, use this.myFunc = () => {...} and access it in the HTML with app.myFunc, but when defining the controller itself, use the normal `function` syntax.

To make things simpler, rather than using `app` in the HTML and `this` in the controller, it is a good idea to use the same name, by assigning `this` to a variable. Commonly people use `vm` (for View Model). So you would have `ControllerAs='vm'`  and then in the JavaScript, set `let vm = this;` at the top of your controller code.

Then you can refer to `vm.name2` (for example) in *both* your HTML and your JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, and I have used the ControllerAs syntax (indexCtrl as app), so when I do app.name2 in view, shouldn't it look for this.name2 in the controller??
Also, what did you mean by 'this is not on $scope'? Is there a way to add it in $scope?

Comment: Please see my expanded answer. Read it carefully. I hope this makes the situation clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**$scope**

The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller).

The scope is an object with the available properties and methods. It is used to get all the controls on the controller.js files.

The scope is available for both the view and the controller.

**this**

When the controller constructor function is called, this is the controller.

Within functions defined on $scope, this is set to the $scope in effect where/when the function was called".

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html ng-app="angularApp">
         <head>
          <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
         </head>
         <body>
          <div ng-controller="indexCtrl as app">
           <input
            type="text"
            ng-model="name1"
            placeholder="Using $scope variable name"
           />
           <br />
           <input
            type="text"
            ng-model="app.name2"
            placeholder="Using this variable name"
           />
           <br /><br />
           <h2 ng-if="name1 != ''"> Hello {{name1}} </h2>
           <br />
           <h2 ng-if="app.name2 != ''"> Hi {{app.name2}} </h2>
          </div>
         </body>
        </html>
    <script>
    angular.module('angularApp', [])
      .controller('indexCtrl', ($scope)=>{
       // Initialize variables
       $scope.name1 = '';
       this.name2 = '';
       $scope.greeting1 = `Hello ${$scope.name1}`;
       this.greeting2 = `Hi ${this.name2}`;
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: "Within functions defined on $scope, 'this' is set to the $scope in effect where/when the function was called".
Could you please clarify this statement a bit more?
Does this mean if I use $scope in a controller and try to use this, all the 'this' will be '$scope'?
And does this mean the program actually looks for $scope.name2 when we do 'app.name2'? instead of looking for this.name2?